# Suddenly "Safari Starts With: A New Window" Setting Is Missing

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I have a macbook pro 13" from 2015 running Mojave at the moment. Recently something odd happened and selection of how safari opens has two options."All windows, and all non-private windows". It used to have one more option called "A New Window" and now it is missing.

I would really love to get rid of anxiety I have each time I open my laptop in a cafe or something because of obvious reasons.
[image: Setting]

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

~bio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setting is dependant on another setting in System Prefs > General > Close Windows when quitting an app.

If that is checked, you get the new Window option. If it is unchecked, then you're essentially telling Safari [& all apps] to remember what they were doing at quit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is rather interesting, because it disabled itself outta nowhere. Anyway, marking this as solved. Thank you for your reply.